# Hadith explanation of Quran 59:7: Where are these cursed activities of ladies in Quran?

Tags: tafseer, hadith-interpretation, surat-al-hashr

> Narrated Alqama
>
> 'Abdullah (bin Masud) said, "Allah curses those ladies who practice
>   tattooing and those who get themselves tattooed, and those ladies who
>   remove the hair from their faces and those who make artificial spaces
>   between their teeth in order to look more beautiful whereby they
>   change Allah's creation." His saying reached a lady from Bani Asd
>   called Um Yaqub who came (to Abdullah) and said, "I have come to know
>   that you have cursed such-and-such (ladies)?" He replied, "Why should
>   I not curse these whom Allah's Apostle has cursed and **who are (cursed)
>   in Allah's Book!**" Um Yaqub said, "I have read the whole Qur'an, but I
>   did not find in it what you say." He said, "Verily, if you have read
>   it (i.e. the Qur'an), you have found it. Didn't you read:
>
> 'And whatsoever the Apostle gives you take it and whatsoever he
>   forbids you, you abstain (from it).' **(59.7)**
>
> She replied, "Yes, I did," He said, "Verily, Allah's Apostle forbade
>   such things." She said, "But I see your wife doing these things?" He
>   said, "Go and watch her." She went and watched her but could not see
>   anything in support of her statement. On that he said, "If my wife was
>   as you thought, I would not keep her in my company."

**Sahih Buckari** Book 60, Hadith 408

but here is the Quranic verse

> And what Allah restored to His Messenger from the people of the towns
>   - it is for Allah and for the Messenger and for [his] near relatives and orphans and the [stranded] traveler - so that it will not be a
>   perpetual distribution among the rich from among you. And whatever the
>   Messenger has given you - take; and what he has forbidden you -
>   refrain from. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty.

**Quran** 59:7

Where is these cursed activities in the Quran?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - are you saying that there is no ban on tattooing mentioned in the Qu'ran?

Comment: Salaam. I'm saying Quran 59:7 doesn't related to this activities.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ayah in Quran that directly mention cursing these activities.

However, the hadith points to this ayah:

> مَّا أَفَاءَ اللَّهُ عَلَىٰ رَسُولِهِ مِنْ أَهْلِ الْقُرَىٰ فَلِلَّهِ وَلِلرَّسُولِ وَلِذِي الْقُرْبَىٰ وَالْيَتَامَىٰ وَالْمَسَاكِينِ وَابْنِ السَّبِيلِ كَيْ لَا يَكُونَ دُولَةً بَيْنَ الْأَغْنِيَاءِ مِنكُمْ ۚ **وَمَا آتَاكُمُ الرَّسُولُ فَخُذُوهُ وَمَا نَهَاكُمْ عَنْهُ فَانتَهُوا ۚ** وَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ ۖ إِنَّ اللَّهَ شَدِيدُ الْعِقَابِ
>
> Sahih International Translation
>
> And what Allah restored to His Messenger from the people of the towns - it is for Allah and for the Messenger and for [his] near relatives and orphans and the [stranded] traveler - so that it will not be a perpetual distribution among the rich from among you. **And whatever the Messenger has given you - take; and what he has forbidden you - refrain from.** And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty.
>
> [[Surat Al-Ĥashr:7]](http://quran.com/59/7)

In this ayah, Allah orders us to believe in what Prophet Muhammad says or gives to us, and to refrain and abstain from whatever Prophet Muhammad has forbidden us. Now the question is: did Prophet Muhammad forbid these activities?

The answer is: yes, he not only forbade these activities, but also cursed women who do them. The fact that Prophet Muhammad has cursed women who do these activities is narrated by many of the Sahabah in many Hadith books, I could mention this Hadith for example:

> Narrated Ibn `Umar:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) has cursed the lady who lengthens her hair artificially and the one who gets her hair lengthened, and also the lady who tattoos (herself or others) and the one who gets herself tattooed.
>
> حَدَّثَنِي مُحَمَّدٌ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدَةُ، عَنْ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ قَالَ لَعَنَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم الْوَاصِلَةَ وَالْمُسْتَوْصِلَةَ، وَالْوَاشِمَةَ وَالْمُسْتَوْشِمَةَ‏.‏
>
> [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/155)

More Hadiths that narrate that can be found in [this search page](http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA).

So to sum it up: **Allah ordered us to believe whatever Prophet Muhammad says as if it was Allah's own rules. And since Prophet cursed women who do these activities, then we understand that women who do these activities are cursed.**

Hope this makes some sense, and Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

it is 4:117-119. https://quran.com/4/115-122 :

> (117:)  They call upon instead of Him none but female [deities], and they [actually] call upon none but a rebellious Satan. (118:) Whom Allah has
>   cursed. For he had said, "I will surely take from among Your servants
>   a specific portion. (119:) And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in
>   them [sinful] desires, and I will command them so they will slit the
>   ears of cattle, and I will command them so they will change the
>   creation of Allah ." And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of
>   Allah has certainly sustained a clear loss.